# Prompted for password in Outlook after restart

Tags: passwords, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a few domain users that wants an external mailaddress as primary mail address in Outlook. (Mostly to have that as default send-as address)

The user account mail address is then added as another mail in the Outlook profile. (Not as an additional mailbox in the account)

These users are prompted for password to the external mail every time they restart their computer.

I have cleared windows vault and re-created the profiles but it doesn't work.

Anyone has a solution for this, or an explanation as to why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Is the AutoDiscovery for the external mail address correct? (Check it [here](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/))

Answer (score 0):

next time it asks your for a password do the following :

Chose another user > in the username field type : DOMAiN\EMAIL or DOMAIN\LDAP depends on how your exchange is configured then type in the password hit remember password once outlook is open close and reopen and voila .

Comment: That doesn't solve it unfortunately.
It's only prompting for password after restart. It might be some GPO that's messing it up. But I can't find it.

Comment: It does ask one more time try again

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Ok let's not give up : control panel > mail > create new profile ( email ) name it email give it its proper name and login setting and use it as your default, now login let it ask you for the password do the steps above. Just for the info does this outlook has several emails connected to it or just 1?

Comment: Hi, thanks for not giving up ;).
I might have been unclear, but yes, they have two emails. For those who have just one email it's not an issue.
I have created new mail profiles for them several times.

It's working fine until I restart the computer, then it prompts for password one time and works fine until next computer restart.

Comment: Can you make sure you're entering the correct credential for the correct email supposing you have 2 emails A and B it's asking you for password for B email and onscreen credentials are A's you have to click more choices and enter B's email and password and hit remember. And btw you need 1 profile only.

Comment: I am entering the correct credentials, it's accepted.
It's just that they get prompted for password again after restart. And there is just on profile.

Comment: Do you mind showing a picture of the credential screen ?